# How to disable end dates on respect to start date in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

How can I disable dates in end date calender based on the date selected in the start date using angular js
For example:if 4th april 2015 is selected in start date in end date part the dates must get enabled from 5the April 2015 i.e end date must not be less than start date.

Here is my html page

```
Start Date
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="">    
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="data.date" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                    </div>    
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                    <datetimepicker data-ng-model="data.date"
                        data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdown2' }">
                    </datetimepicker>
                </ul>
            End Date
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="">    
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="data.date" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                    </div>    
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                    <datetimepicker data-ng-model="data.date"
                        data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdown2' }">
                    </datetimepicker>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this way

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({
  onRender: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
  }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
  if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
    var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
    checkout.setValue(newDate);
  }
  checkin.hide();
  $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
}).data('datepicker');
var checkout = $('#dpd2').datepicker({
  onRender: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
  }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
  checkout.hide();
}).data('datepicker');
```

Here i have used jquery..